# Move pattern to beginning of line

Tags: grep, sed, regex

I am trying to reformat a log file such that date and time appear at the beginning of the line.  My logs look like this:

```
blah, blah, blah, Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:59:42
yadi, yadi, yada, Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:51:11
```

I would like them to look like this:

```
Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:59:42 blah, blah, blah
Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:51:11 yadi, yadi, yada
```

I have gone so far as to find the right grep pattern with `grep -o -i -e '[a-zA-Z]*, [a-z][a-z][a-z] [0-9]*,[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' ~/log.txt` .

How can I move these pattern results to the left of the information string?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `sed` with the following regex:

```bsh
$ sed -i.bak 's_\(.*\),[[:blank:]]\([[:alpha:]]\+,[[:blank:]][[:alpha:]]\+[[:blank:]][[:digit:]]\+,[^,]\+$\)_\2 \1_' file.txt 
Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:59:42 blah, blah, blah
Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:51:11 yadi, yadi, yada
```

Here we have used the `sed`'s group substitution method to get the desired output.

- `\(.*\)` will match upto `blah, blah, blah` as we have `,[[:blank:]]` to match `,` after it.
- `\([[:alpha:]]\+,[[:blank:]][[:alpha:]]\+[[:blank:]][[:digit:]]\+,[^,]\+$\)` will match the remaining portion of the line (the portion we want to put at the start).

Then we have `\2 \1` to put the second group at first and then then a space and then the first group.

The original file will be backed up as `file.txt.bak`, if you don't want that use just `-i` instead of `-i.bak`.

**Although you will get the desired output, using Regex/sed will not be the optimum solution in this case.

**EDIT:** If you have a line like `[Internet disconnected] Friday, Mar 13,2015 15:48:34`, try this:

```bsh
$ sed -i.bak 's_\(.*[^,]\),*[[:blank:]]\([[:alpha:]]\+,[[:blank:]][[:alpha:]]\+[[:blank:]][[:digit:]]\+,[^,]\+$\)_\2 \1_' file.txt 
Friday, Mar 13,2015 15:48:34 [Internet disconnected]
Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:59:42 blah, blah, blah
Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:51:11 yadi, yadi, yada
```

In the previous regex we had `\(.*\),[[:blank:]]` (a comma and a whitespace after the first matching group), now to include the new line in the output we have made the first matching group `\(.*[^,]\)` to ensure that it does not end with a comma and then we have matched `,*` i.e. one or more commas. So, the new `sed` command will work for all mentioned cases.

Comment: I am still trying to grasp the pattern matching magic you applied (although with little success), and I have just noticed that there is an issue with certain lines such as this one: `[Internet disconnected] Friday, Mar 13,2015 15:48:34` - can you help?

Comment: @Tfb9: Please check my edits..if you need any further help regarding any part of the regex let me know..also it would be more compact if i have the generals patterns at once..

Comment: @Tfb9: Check the new edit..Now its more compact..

Comment: Thank you very much!  This seems to work on all my test cases and even gets rid of the trailing comma.  I think the hard part for me right now is simply parsing sed's substitute command in my head - I am new at this.  The answer was perfect, but I did not want to draw attention to the first part of strings as only the right-hand part was predictable. For example: `[Initialized, firmware version: V1.0.1.0.1] Friday, Mar 13,2015 15:48:31`  `[DoS attack: ACK Scan] attack packets in last 20 sec from ip [192.168.211.10], Friday, Mar 20,2015 18:59:21`

Comment: @Tfb9: Glad to hear that..[[:blank:]] matches a space or a tab, `+` matches 1 or more occurrences of the previous match, [[:digit:]] matches 0 to 9, [[:alpha:]] matches [a-zA-Z], `[^,]` matches any character other than comma..hope you will be more clear now..

Answer (score 4):

with awk it is much simpler syntax

```
awk -F, '{print $4","$5","$6","$1","$2","$3}' file.txt
```

Comment: Note that this assumes each line has the same number of fields. Since the first few seem to be variable, this will likely fail.

Answer (score 3):

The golden rule of regular expressions is "less is more". You should always try to write the simplest regex that matches your data. That not only makes it much easier to read and understand, it is also much more robust and won't break with small changes in format. So, in your case, you could simply do:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*), ([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]*$)/\2\1/' file 
Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:59:42blah, blah, blah, 
Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:51:11yadi, yadi, yada,
```

That matches everything from the beginning of the line until a comma and space (`(.*),`) and, because the pattern is surrounded by parentheses, saves it as `\1`. Now, because the second captured group (second pattern in parentheses) goes up to the end of the line (that's what the `$` means), we know we're matching the right part in the first one.

The second looks for a stretch of one or more non-comma characters (`[^,]+`), a comma, another set of non-commas, another comma and then as many non-comma characters as possible until the end of the line. That way, we can correctly identify the last fields as the date. The `s///` is the substitution operator which here simply switches the order of the 1st and 2nd captured pattern.

You could also do the same thing in `awk`. Presumably, the text before the date is variable so we can't assume the same number of fields for each line. Therefore, we will need to count the fields backwards from the end of the line:

```
$ awk -F, '{ 
            printf "%s,%s,%s, ", $(NF-2),$(NF-1),$NF; 
            for(i=1;i<NF-3;i++){printf "%s,", $i} print $(NF-3)
         }' file 
 Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:59:42, blah, blah, blah
 Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:51:11, yadi, yadi, yada
```

Or in Perl:

```
$ perl -lpe 's/(.*), ([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]*$)/\2, \1/' file 
Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:59:42, blah, blah, blah
Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:51:11, yadi, yadi, yada

$ perl -F, -lane 'print join ",",@F[$#F-2,$#F-1,$#F,0..$#F-3]' file 
 Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:59:42,blah, blah, blah
 Friday, Mar 13,2015 16:51:11,yadi, yadi, yada
```